# E_Bikes.site not found

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm working on the **Push and Deploy Lightning Web Component Files** module of LWC Basics trailhead.

The trailhead involves installing e-bikes using the Salesforce DX. 
I followed the steps for installing the app and pushing it to the scratch org as mentioned in the below resource:
https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc#installing-e-bikes-using-salesforce-dx

Now, it involves deploying e-bikes to the Trailhead Playground that I created for LWC Module. i.e, to a permanent environment.

I performed the 2 steps under it which involves authenticating the Development Org and then checking out a new branch. Till this step, everything looks in place.

Now, the next step says: **In VS Code, use the Ctrl/Cmd-P shortcut for Quick Open. Type E_Bikes.site and click on the E_Bikes.site-meta.xml file to open it.**

When I go to VS code, press Ctrl+P, and enter E_bikes, it says no result found. 
Can someone please help me understand what I've missed here.

Comment: I added the DevOrg instructions, so I hope I can help. You'll have to have the E_bikes folder open in VS Code for the Quick Open to work. You can either use the  File ->  Open Folder... menu in VS Code, or it might be easier to close VS Code, and run `code .` from the command line, in the same place you've been running the other commands. That opens VS Code to the current folder.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor thanks so much for the instant reply. I used the command line to align the folders and it worked. I'm still new to the VS Code and CLI, so still getting used to it. I hope I catch up quickly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this one was confusing  based on how its detailed in trailhead instructions. So to resolve this here is what you should do and I did the same.

1. Follow the instruction for Scratch org development push the source.
2. Once you are done with scratch org follow the git instruction to setup the .git repo in DevHub org (In github instruction this one is after the other in Scratch org https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc#installing-e-bikes-using-a-developer-edition-org)

The confusion exist as in scratch org we do not setup the sites and those instructions are present in setting up for DEV org. 
Step 6 onwards in DEVHUB org

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: But offcourse it does. I provided the set of instruction which needs to be followed since the site related settings only appear after completing these instructions. @derek f did you complete this badge?

Comment: OP (**O**rigianl **P**oster of the question) is already following the instructions that you linked to (and, in fact, provided the same link). The question isn't so much about how to deploy to a non-scratch org as it is about "why can't VSCode find this file?". So, I still don't think this answers the question. Thomas Taylor's comment (which really should've been an answer) gets to the heart of OP's issue here.

Comment: OP is not able to find the sites. He posted an update like 5 hours back about his inability. Thomas's comment just helped OP with a command to start vs code but not help him to resolve e_bikes related instruction. If I were you I would wait for OP to decide on this and then downvote the answer.

Comment: I completed this trailhead challenge today and even raised a ticket with trailhead for the confusing text in trailhead unit.

Comment: Please take a closer look. OP is "Ashutosh Arora", and the person who answered five hours ago is "Divyanshu Sharma". These would appear to be two completely different people. I find that taking the time to read and fully comprehend questions and comments helps in writing more accurate answers.

Comment: Yes that's what I overlooked in my excitement to help divyanshu in this case and not OP. Will be cautious next time. Thanks for pointing the issue Derek.